# How to load a new table view in xcode

Tags: tableview

I have the below Container View Controller with a next button. How do I add a new table view controller in a container view controller very time I click the next button?
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to just add another cell to the existing table view? Having so many tables on a single screen doesn't seem practical.

Comment: @Russ J - I don't know what to do, not that I don't want to. So do I just add another prototype Cells in the same table?

Comment: Give Apple's tutorial on the subject a good read. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html

Comment: Essentially, it's best to only have one table view per page, then customize prototype cells for each kind of data you want to show.